# Extend the construction of derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, chain-rule, frechet-derivative

I'm reading about derivative in Amann's *Analysis I*. The authors define derivative for functions defined on arbitrary subset of $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$. To ensure that the operation of taking limit is meaningful, the authors use the concept of *limit point*.
[image]
I'm trying to do the same for vector-valued functions. Could you have a check if my construction makes sense? It seems the chain rule still holds in this extended definition.

---

Let $(E, |\cdot|_E)$ and $(F, |\cdot|_F)$ be normed vector space. Let $X$ be an *arbitrary* non-empty subset of $E$. Notice that we do not require $X$ to be open in $E$. Let $f: X \to F$ and $a \in X$ be a *limit* point of $X$, there is at least one sequence $(x_n) \subset X \setminus \{a\}$ such that $x_n \to a$. We say that $f$ is *differentiable* at $a$ if there is $A \in \mathcal L(E, F)$ such that
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a) - A(x-a)}{|x-a|_E} = 0_F.
$$

It is easy to verify that the following statements are equivalent, i.e.,

- $f$ is differentiable at $a$.
- there is $A \in \mathcal L(E, F)$ such that
  $$
  f(x) = f(a)+ A(x-a) + o(|x-a|_E) \quad \text{as} \quad x \to a.
  $$
- there is $A \in \mathcal L(E, F)$ and $r:X \to F$ such that $r(a)=0$, $r$ is contious at $a$, and
  $$
  f(x) = f(a)+ A(x-a) + r(x)|x-a|_E \quad \forall x \in X.
  $$

Here $o(|x-a|_E)$ is the Landau little-o symbol. We call such $A$ *a derivative* of $f$ at $a$. We do *not* know whether such $A$ is unique or not. Let denote it by $\partial f (a)$. Even if $\partial f (a)$ may not be unique, we always have if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then it is continuous at $a$.

> **Theorem:** Let $(G, |\cdot|_G)$ be a normed vector space. Let $f:X \to F$, $Y:=f(X)$, and $g:Y \to G$. Assume $a\in X$ is a limit point of $X$, and $b:=f(a)$ a limit point of $Y$. If $f, g$ are differentiable at $a,b$ respectively, then $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $a$, and
> $$
> \partial (g \circ f) (a) = [\partial g (b)] \circ [\partial f a].
> $$

**Proof:** Because $f$ is differentiable at $a$, there is $r:X \to F$ such that $r(a)=0$, $r$ is continous at $a$, and
$$
f(x) = f(a)+ \partial f (a)(x-a) + r(x)|x-a|_E \quad \forall x \in X.
$$

Because $g$ is differentiable at $b$,  there is $s:Y \to G$ such that $s(b)=0$, $s$ is continuous at $b$, and
$$
g(y) = g(b)+ \partial g (b)(y-b) + s(y)|y-b|_F \quad \forall y \in Y.
$$

We replace $y$ by $f(x)$ and $b$ by $f(a)$, and get
$$
\begin{align}
g \circ f (x) &= g \circ f (a) + \partial g (b)[\partial f (a)(x-a) + r(x)|x-a|_E] \\
& \quad + (s \circ f (x)) |\partial f (a)(x-a) + r(x)|x-a|_E|_F.
\end{align}
$$

Because $\partial g (b)$ is linear, we get
$$
\begin{align}
g \circ f (x) &= g \circ f (a) + [\partial g (b)] \circ [\partial f (a)](x-a) + |x-a|_E \partial g (b)(r(x)) \\
& \quad + (s \circ f (x)) |\partial f (a)(x-a) + r(x)|x-a|_E|_F.
\end{align}
$$

Reorganizing a little bit, we get
$$
g \circ f (x) = g \circ f (a) + [\partial g (b)] \circ [\partial f (a)](x-a) + t(x)|x-a|_E,
$$
where
$$
t(x) = \begin{cases}
\partial g (b)(r(x)) + (s \circ f (x)) \left |\partial f (a) \left (\frac{x-a}{|x-a|_E} \right) + r(x) \right |_F & \text{if} \quad x \neq a \\
0 & \text{if} \quad x = a.
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly, $t$ is continuous for all $x \neq a$. It remains to prove $\lim_{x \to a} t(a)=0$. We have
$$
|\partial g (b)(r(x))|_G \le \|\partial g (b)\| \cdot |r(x)|_F \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad x \to a.
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
&| s \circ f (x)|_G \cdot \left | \partial f (a) \left (\frac{x-a}{|x-a|_E} \right) + r(x) \right |_F \\
\le &|s \circ f (x)|_G \cdot \left ( \|\partial f (a)\|  + |r(x)|_F \right ) \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad x \to a.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: A side remark: The classical notion of differentiable function is usually restricted to Banach spaces (**complete** normed vector spaces). Completeness may appear superfluous but is in fact very useful (for fixed point issues in particular). There are larger generalizations, like distributional derivatives, but with less in common with our "ordinary differentials" (or derivatives if you prefer).

Comment: What happens if $X=\{a\}$? Does the 
""arbitrary, non-empty" specification make sense?

Comment: @NickD I define derivative for only limit  points.

Comment: Except for not requiring $X$ to be open, this is the definition of the Frechet derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). Do you have an application in mind that requires $X$ to not be open?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You're right! I actually want to apply this kind of definition to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540778/does-this-version-of-inverse-function-theorem-hold-for-banach-space) version of inverse function theorem.

Comment: Since derivatives are not unique, the chain rule correctly reads as follows: If $df(x_0)$ is **a** derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ and $dg(y_0)$ is **a** derivative of $g$ at $y_0=f(x_0)$ then $dg(y_0)\circ df(x_0)$ is **a** derivative of $g\circ f$ at $x_0$. 
The restriction to *limit points* of the source of $f$ does not help very much and should be removed from the definition (if, e.g., $x_0$ is isolated in the domain, then every $A\in L(X,Y)$ is a derivative-- why not?). 
@QiaochuYuan Aren't embedded manifolds natural enough to consider functions on non-open domains?